# GraphQL client side layer on Realm

Tags: react-native, realm, graphql

Is there a way to have GraphQL layer on the client side Realm database?
I have react-native app with Realm integration but I would like to do queries on the Realm db not doing queries directly.

Something like `SQLite`

Answer (score 1):

The Realm platform does support GraphQL for remote access (see https://realm.io/blog/realm-scales-to-the-web/). So if you are using synchronized Realms you could use that.

I don't think there is any way to do GraphQL queries against local realms, but it shouldn't be too hard to build a wrapper to expose that, but why would you want to do that over direct queries (which are likely to be much more performant)?